# Permutations and inversion question for the set {$1,2,3,4,5,6$}

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> How many permutations of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ have exactly 13 inversions?

I have no idea how to start this problem? Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: How many inversions does $6,5,4,3,2,1$ have?

Comment: 1?  The inversion sequence goes exactly as the sequence stated.

Comment: I am assuming the definition of inversions described here: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL4/MARGOLIUS/inversions.pdf in the section 'Introduction'  So I would say, 15 inversions.

Comment: I just asked my friend what he has for the answer. He said he got $\binom{5}{2} + \binom{4}{1}$ permutations with 13 inversions.  Do you know how he got the answer and if he is right?

Comment: I thought you wanted a hint.

Comment: It will be much easier if the question was asking for how many permutations have exactly 15 inversions.  Because that would be $\binom{6}{0}$